# What does a Bonus Titan Break Gem do?

Tags: infinity-blade-2

I recently acquired a hexagon gem called Bonus Titan Break Gem. The description of its effect is:

`TITAN BREAK +1`

What exactly does that mean? Is each break a second longer? Do I get a free break somehow? Does it affect all types of breaks (parry, block, dodge)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Titan Break Gems: Gems that can be applied to armors for a larger attack window when fighting a titan. Values of +1 or +2 allow for 1 or 2 more hits, respectively.

That's taken straight from [the website](http://infinityblade.wikia.com/wiki/Moves).

Answer (score 2):

I found a +2 bonus titan break and at first I thought that it might increase the likelihood of a successful block, dodge or parry triggering a break but I don't believe that this is the case. Since equipping it, I've noticed that the size of the hit window for each break is higher than it used to be, sometimes as many as 8 hits, which leads me to believe that this style of gem increases the hit window of breaks by the number indicated on the gem. I don't have any empirical evidence to support this, it's just my observations for now.